# Php - check if string is not empty or has a first character not equal to

Tags: php

How can I check in php if the string is empty or has a first character not equal to something.
If I do this to an empty string `$key = ''`:

```
if ($key != '' || $key[0] != '_')
```

I get:

> Uninitialized string offset: 0

Comment: Show the value of variable

Comment: Like I wrote it is an empty string, but I will add this to the question as well

Comment: why don't you use AND in if condition ...?

Comment: If the string is empty it is still set, so I do want to check if it is not empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isset` for not having offset[0]

```
if ($key != '' || (isset($key[0]) && $key[0] != '_' )) {
   echo "First Character not equal with _";
}
```

Comment: this is weird, I thought this would work but on checking the $key value inside the block I get an empty array, I will further expand my question with your answer

Comment: Try using `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: I did, but I still get the same thing, I have expanded my question

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
if(trim($key)==''||substr( $key, 0, 1)=='_'){
   echo ' string is  empty or start with _';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below will check for an empty string and will also check the first character.

```
if ( strlen($str) > 0 ) {

    if ( $str[0] !== $a_char ){
        echo "My first char did not match that char.";
    } else {
        echo "My first char matched that char.";
    }

} else {

    echo 'String is empty. Therefore, no point checking the first character.';

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
    //$key = "";
    $something = "h";

    if (!isset($key) || substr( $key, 0, 1) !== $something || empty($key) ) {
        echo('undefined / empty string or string starts with: '.$something);;
    } else {
        echo('b');
    }
```

`$something` is the character you want to compare with

Example: if $key is undefined or `""`
[image]

Comment: No, and it should be ```!empty($key)``` because I don't want to enter block of code if the string is empty

Comment: @leff but you said "string is empty or has a first character not equal to something"

so empty($key) // string is empty
|| // or
substr( $key, 0, 1) !== $something //  first character not equal to $something

Comment: sorry, you are right, I just saw the title, but it is still not working

Comment: @Leff can you tell me what you used for `$key` and what you used for `$something` to make it 'still not working'?

Comment: I have expanded my question, and like I said you can test it with an empty string and see that it will fail

Comment: @leff `empty` string is "", not an undefined / `!isset` string right?